# set -u usage not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I am learning how to efficiently use different `set` options in my script and came across `set -u` that appears to be perfect for exiting my script if a variable does not get set properly (ex. deleting users). According to the **man** page, `set -u` and `set -e` does the following...

```
-e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
-u  Treat unset variables as an error when substituting.
```

I created a test script to test this functionality, but it does not appear to be working as expected. Perhaps someone could better explain my issue to me and where I am mis-interpreting? Test script is below. Thank you.

```
set -e
set -u
testing="This works"
echo $?
echo ${testing}
testing2=
echo $?
echo ${testing2}
testing3="This should not appear"
echo $?
echo ${testing3}
```

I expect the script to display **0** and **"This works"**, and then fail as `${testing2}` is not set.

Instead I am displayed **0** and **"This works"**, follow by **0** and then **0** **This should not appear**

Can anyone provide some knowledge? Thank you.

Comment: So followup... is there any way to make setting a variable to the null string illegal/raise an error? I'm guessing not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From "man Bash":

> A parameter is set if it has been assigned a value.  The null string is a valid value.  Once a variable is set, it may be unset only by using the unset builtin command.

When you do `testing2=` you are setting the variable to the null string.

Change that to `unset testing2` and try again.

---

The `set -e` does not help in this case as an assignment never has an exit code of 1. Try this to see that the last command executed (the assignment) has an exit code of 0, or [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20157938/2350426):

```
$ false; a=""; echo $?
0
```

And I also believe that the use of set -e is more a problem that a solution.

What may get an error with the use of unset variables is `set -u`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u
testing="This works"
echo ${testing}
unset testing2
echo ${testing2}
testing3="This should not appear"
echo ${testing3}
```

Will output:

```
$  ./script.sh
This works
./script.sh: line 9: testing2: unbound variable
```

Answer (score 3):

`testing2=` sets the `testing2` variable to an empty string; the variable actually *is set*.

However if you were to run `echo $testing99` in an interactive Bash shell (without setting `errexit`, i.e., `set -e`), you would get an error:

```
bash: testing99: unbound variable
```

#### Aside

While testing scripts just now, I discovered that an *interactive* shell  **does not always exit** when attempting to expand a variable that *hasn’t been set* while a *non-interactive* shell (running a shell script) **always exits**. According to the POSIX man page for `set`:

> -u      The shell shall write a message to standard error when it tries to
>   expand a variable that is not set and immediately exit. An interactive shell shall not exit.

An interactive Bash shell won’t exit unless `errexit` has *also* been set. On the other hand, an interactive dash shell won’t exit – even if `set -e` has previously been run.

Comment: If dash does not exit with set -e; set -u; unset aa; echo $aa, then dash is wrong.

Comment: @schily When I first noticed this, I figured that the dash authors knew better than me and that there may have been some ambiguity in the POSIX specifications but having re-checked http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html, I agree that looks like a bug, alright.

Comment: There is a simple rule: when both Korn Shell and Bourne Shell agree and another shell implementation has a deviation, then the other shell behaves incorrectly.